# Angular 4 @ngx-translate Karma Jasmin test cases

Tags: karma-jasmine, bootstrap-4, translate, ngx-translate

Trying to integrate **Angular 4 + @ngx-translate**. Everything is executing and working properly with  `npm start`. Problem arises when I tries to `npm test` run Karma test cases. All these started after adding @ngx-translate capabilities. 
**Console get below error:**

```
20 09 2017 14:24:30.334:INFO [Chrome 60.0.3112 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket n1uvSjMzMfCGU26zAAAA with id 7587189
Chrome 60.0.3112 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Injectable' of undefined
  at node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/bundles/core.umd.js:817
```

**On browser console:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Injectable' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (core.umd.js:817)
    at __webpack_require__ (core.umd.js:30)
    at Object.module.exports (core.umd.js:1421)
    at __webpack_require__ (core.umd.js:30)
    at module.exports (core.umd.js:76)
    at core.umd.js:79
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (core.umd.js:9)
    at core.umd.js:10
ng-bootstrap.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'core' of undefined
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (ng-bootstrap.js:9)
    at ng-bootstrap.js:10
```

**On browser:**

```
OtherComponent when inside a test host should process Instance name
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bpmWrapWorkItemList' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bpmWrapWorkItemList' of undefined
```

Please help !!! I am new to Angular 4..

Answer (score 1):

Please put beforeEach  block to update language for translateservice

```
beforeEach(inject([TranslateService], (service: TranslateService) => {
    service.use('de');
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and was able to resolve the problem by removing two script definitions in `.angular-cli.json`.

I replaced

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/bundles/core.umd.js",
    "../node_modules/@ngx-translate/http-loader/bundles/http-loader.umd.js"
],
```

with

```
"scripts": [],
```

While this resolves the problem, and the translate service still works, I do not know why those scripts are required in the first place, and if it's okay to remove them.